# Create variables from for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I would like to create a large number of sequential variables in a dataframe (many more than in the dummy data below). I have tried using `for (i in a:b)` (see below) however I cannot make this work.

```
 # Create test dataframe #

    test<-as.data.frame(1:15)
    test$X16<-10
    test$P_15<-20
    test$P_16<-25
    colnames(test)[1]<-"X15"

    # Proposed do loop #

    for (i in 15:16){
      test$rate_[[i]]<-1000*test$X[[i]]/test$P_[[i]]
    }
```

EDIT - The solution proposed by  Karsten W works perfectly, thanks.

```
for (i in 15:16){
  test[[paste("rate_", i, sep="")]]<-1000*test[[paste("X", i, sep="")]]/test[[paste("P_", i, sep="")]]
}
```

Comment: Try `test[[paste("X", i, sep="")]]`, etc

Comment: If I read it correctly, they're trying to match cases, i.e., X15 with P_15. Regular expressions are probably the most general answer.

Comment: You don't need a loop. Why not just `test[paste("rate_", 15:16)] <-1000*test[paste0("X", 15:16)]/test[paste0("P_", 15:16)]` ? `*` and `/` are fully vectorized...

Comment: @KonradRudolph he uses `paste` because he can't refer to an existing column using `X[[15]]` when he wants the `X15` column, for example. He also wants to create `test$rate_i` column for each `i`. If you have a solution without using `paste` that would be refreshing.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ah, I overlooked the fact that this was a `data.frame`. My comment doesn’t apply here. That said, a way to make this work is to create an intermediate list and `cbind` that to the existing `data.frame`. Setting the `colnames` would still require `paste` of course but in itself that isn’t bad of course.